# How to ignore testing of one of the attribute in an argument passed in function using verify method of Mockk

Tags: kotlin, mockk-verify

As I need to test publish function parameter passed is correct using Mockk in Kotlin

Below is the code :

```
   val notificationData = NotificationData(
                notificationId = "test-notificationID",
                operation = "CREATE",
                partnerName = "test-partner",
                created = Instant.now().toEpochMilli().toString(),
                services = []
            )
    verify(exactly = 1) { publish(notificationData) }
```

But as the created attribute in notificationData object will be having real time value in mock as well as in called function, both are not matching and giving below error

Verification failed: call 1 of 1: publish(eq(NotificationData(notificationId=test-notificationId, partnerName=test-partner, operation=CREATE, mutatedAttributes=null, services=[], created=1633719398360)))). Only one matching call to Notification(object Notification)/publish(NotificationData) happened, but arguments are not matching:
[0]: argument: NotificationData(notificationId=test-notificationId, partnerName=test-partner, operation=CREATE, mutatedAttributes=null, services=[], created=1633719398404), matcher: eq(NotificationData(notificationId=test-notificationId, partnerName=test-partner, operation=CREATE, mutatedAttributes=null, services=[], created=1633719398360)), result: -

Anyone please help me to find out, how can I ignore the "created" attribute to get test successful

Answer (score 0):

As you were intending to test, it seems you can also mock the `created` as well. Therefore, instead of using `Instant.now().toEpochMilli().toString()`, you should put a time milis value to those `created`, e.g.

```kotlin
val notificationData = NotificationData(
                notificationId = "test-notificationID",
                operation = "CREATE",
                partnerName = "test-partner",
                created = "1633719398404",
                services = []
            )
```

**EDIT**

Seems there is another approach that may help, but quite takes effort, by injecting the `NotificationData` instead in your original class. So, you can mock the `NotificationData` in your test

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but mocking the created attribute with sample timestamp won't work, as in original function it will be called and that time the attribute will get the real time value and the comparison will get failed. So this won't work. So I am asking is there any way to ignore this attribute to be tested as it value is real time value in "timestamp"

Comment: Okay, I have another suggestion, let me update the answer

Comment: As I had reported this issue to Mockk Git, Below is the link for the solution which worked for me
https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/720